# How to update the selectedIndex after calling my own function inside the NavigationRail?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, setstate, mobile-development

I've been working on a Flutter app for a few days now.

I've implemented a [NavigationRail](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRail-class.html) for my app. It works pretty well, excepted for one thing.

When I tap on a [NavigationRailDestination](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRailDestination-class.html), it calls the function *updateRoute(index)* and goes to the required route.

My problem is that, the *selectedIndex* property udpates, but then, when the new route is loaded, the selectedIndex goes back to 0.

Here is my code :

```js
class SidebarDrawer extends StatefulWidget {

  final VoidCallback callbackOnScreenChange;

  SidebarDrawer({@required this.callbackOnScreenChange});

  @override
  _SidebarDrawerState createState() => _SidebarDrawerState();
}

class _SidebarDrawerState extends State<SidebarDrawer> {

  int index = 0;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => NavigationRail(
        extended: isExtended,
        onDestinationSelected: (index) => updateRoute(index),
        selectedIndex: index,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.reorder),
          onPressed: () => setState(() => isExtended = !isExtended),
        ),
        destinations: <NavigationRailDestination>[
          <Some NavigationRailDestination>
        ],
      );

  void updateRoute(index) {
  
    setState(() => this.index = index);
    
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return navigateToScreen(
            context, '/home', widget.callbackOnScreenChange);
      case 1:
        return navigateToScreen(
            context, '/orderManager', widget.callbackOnScreenChange);
      case 2:
        return navigateToScreen(
            context, '/manualControl', widget.callbackOnScreenChange);
      default:
        return navigateToScreen(
            context, '/home', widget.callbackOnScreenChange);
    }
  }
```

The function navigateToScreen() :

```js
/// Navigate to given widget
void navigateToScreen(BuildContext context, String route,
    VoidCallback callbackOnScreenChange) async {
  // Call callback on screen change
  if (callbackOnScreenChange != null) {
    callbackOnScreenChange();
  }

  // Check the current route
  String currentRoute = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name;

  // If the current route is not the same as the new route change the screen
  if (currentRoute != route) {
    await Navigator.pushNamed(context, route);
  }
}
```

I am new to Flutter, I am struggling a bit to understand how does the state works and updates.

I would really appreciate if you could help me understand it please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to correct it.

In my parent widget (`MainScaffold`), I pass an index value to my child widget (containing the `NavigationRail`).

Then in my *NavigationRail* Widget, instead of having the property :
`selectedIndex: index`
I set it to `selectedIndex: widget.selectedDrawerIndex`.

Then on each screen, when I render the main scaffold, I set the required `selectedDrawerIndex` value.

Here is the code from the `sidebar` Widget :

```js
class SidebarDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  // Index is used to know which icon is selected
  final int selectedDrawerIndex;
  final VoidCallback callbackOnScreenChange;

  SidebarDrawer({@required this.selectedDrawerIndex, @required this.callbackOnScreenChange});

  @override
  _SidebarDrawerState createState() => _SidebarDrawerState();
}

class _SidebarDrawerState extends State<SidebarDrawer> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => NavigationRail(
        selectedIndex: widget.selectedDrawerIndex,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.reorder),
          onPressed: () => setState(() => isExtended = !isExtended),
        ),
        // When a destination is selected, the routes are updated
        onDestinationSelected: (selectedDrawerIndex) => updateRoute(selectedDrawerIndex),
        destinations: <NavigationRailDestination>[
          [...some navigation rail destinations...]
        ],
      );

  void updateRoute(selectedDrawerIndex) {
    // Navigate to a specific screen when a destination is clicked
    switch (selectedDrawerIndex) {
      case 0:
        return navigateToScreen(
            context, '/home', widget.callbackOnScreenChange);
      case 1:
        return navigateToScreen(
            context, '/orderManager', widget.callbackOnScreenChange);
      case 2:
        return navigateToScreen(
            context, '/manualControl', 
      default:
        return navigateToScreen(
            context, '/home', widget.callbackOnScreenChange);
    }
  }
}
```

And then in the main scaffold:

```js
class MainScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  final int selectedDrawerIndex;
  final Widget body;
  // Callback when a screen change is requested
  // This is the current way to make sure a screen calls its dispose method when the screen changes
  final VoidCallback callbackOnScreenChange;

  MainScaffold(
      {@required this.selectedDrawerIndex,
      @required this.body,
      this.callbackOnScreenChange});
      
  [...some more code...]
}
```

Then I just need to pass the *selectedDrawerIndex* as parameter when using the MainScaffold Widget.

It works well but I am willing to improve so if you think about a better solution, do not hesitate to post it.